# Ignite client unstable since upgrade from 2.7.0 to 2.9.0

Tags: ignite

We upgraded a bunch of libraries in our application one of them is ignite. Right now the ignite running in client mode is crashing. My thinking is that one of the upgrades caused the cache to have increased in size. (so I don't think the upgrade of ignite is the problem).

So I increased the heap size from 10 to 20 GB. But when about 50% is used the JVM hangs.

I'm confused on why it does this when there is only 50% in use.

```
[12/3/20 16:07:58:788 GMT] 000000c4 IgniteKernal I .... Heap [used=9937MB, free=51.48%, comm=10680MB]
```

followed by

```
[12/3/20 16:08:26:410 GMT] 000000bd IgniteKernal  W   Possible too long JVM pause: 2418 milliseconds.
[12/3/20 16:08:27:465 GMT] 000000c5 TcpCommunicat W   Client disconnected abruptly due to network connection loss or because the connection was left open on application shutdown. [cls=class o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridNioException, msg=Connection reset by peer]

[12/3/20 16:08:27:411 GMT] 000000c5 TcpCommunicat E   Failed to process selector key [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=DirectNioClientWorker [super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=0, bytesRcvd=48849402273, bytesSent=15994664546, bytesRcvd0=54446, bytesSent0=102, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-0, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1607011706410, hashCode=433635054, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-0-#51]]], writeBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], readBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], inRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=9025120, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=9025150, sentCnt=9025152, reserved=true, lastAck=9025120, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=b3ca311e-077f-42a5-884a-807b539730b6, consistentId=10.60.46.12:48500, addrs=ArrayList [10.60.46.12], sockAddrs=HashSet [hex-wgc-p-web02/10.60.46.12:48500], discPort=48500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1607006097079, loc=false, ver=2.9.0#20201015-sha1:70742da8, isClient=false], connected=false, connectCnt=1, queueLimit=4096, reserveCnt=1, pairedConnections=false], outRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=9025120, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=9025150, sentCnt=9025152, reserved=true, lastAck=9025120, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=b3ca311e-077f-42a5-884a-807b539730b6, consistentId=10.60.46.12:48500, addrs=ArrayList [10.60.46.12], sockAddrs=HashSet [hex-wgc-p-web02/10.60.46.12:48500], discPort=48500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1607006097079, loc=false, ver=2.9.0#20201015-sha1:70742da8, isClient=false], connected=false, connectCnt=1, queueLimit=4096, reserveCnt=1, pairedConnections=false], closeSocket=true, outboundMessagesQueueSizeMetric=o.a.i.i.processors.metric.impl.LongAdderMetric@69a257d1, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/10.223.132.3:52550, rmtAddr=/10.60.46.12:48100, createTime=1607006097572, closeTime=0, bytesSent=15994657850, bytesRcvd=48849402273, bytesSent0=102, bytesRcvd0=54446, sndSchedTime=1607006097572, lastSndTime=1607011706410, lastRcvTime=1607011706410, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridDirectParser@93200255, directMode=true], GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter], accepted=false, markedForClose=false]]]
                                 java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:235)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:204)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$DirectNioClientWorker.processRead(GridNioServer.java:1330)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:2472)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:2239)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1880)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:822)
[12/3/20 16:08:44:437 GMT] 000000c4 SystemOut     O [16:08:44] Possible failure suppressed accordingly to a configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, err=class o.a.i.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=tcp-comm-worker, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1607011706420]]]
[12/3/20 16:08:44:436 GMT] 000000c4               W java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger log Possible failure suppressed accordingly to a configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, err=class o.a.i.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=tcp-comm-worker, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1607011706420]]]
                                 class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=tcp-comm-worker, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1607011706420]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance$3.apply(IgnitionEx.java:1806)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance$3.apply(IgnitionEx.java:1801)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.worker.WorkersRegistry.onIdle(WorkersRegistry.java:234)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.onIdle(GridWorker.java:297)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.timeout.GridTimeoutProcessor$TimeoutWorker.body(GridTimeoutProcessor.java:221)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:822)
[12/3/20 16:08:44:434 GMT] 000000c4 G             W   Thread [name="tcp-comm-worker-#1-#63", id=211, state=WAITING, blockCnt=2, waitCnt=100]
[12/3/20 16:08:44:432 GMT] 000000c4 G             E   Blocked system-critical thread has been detected. This can lead to cluster-wide undefined behaviour [workerName=tcp-comm-worker, threadName=tcp-comm-worker-#1-#63, blockedFor=18s]
[12/3/20 16:09:14:486 GMT] 000000c4 SystemOut     O [16:09:14] Possible failure suppressed accordingly to a configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, err=class o.a.i.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=tcp-comm-worker, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1607011736000]]]
```

Comment: You're seeing a long JVM pauses of 2.5 seconds. For some reason it is linked to connection resets (which is not caused by Ignite probably). But it should not in itself lead to client disconnect. What's your failure detection timeout?

Comment: I'm not changing any timeout settings so the default values.

Comment: Then it should be around 10s or more, should not lead to client disconnecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These look like network issues.

[12/3/20 16:08:27:411 GMT] 000000c5 TcpCommunicat E   Failed to process selector key

[workerName=tcp-comm-worker, threadName=tcp-comm-worker-#1-#63, blockedFor=18s]

Check that you are able to connect from your client machines to your server machines and that firewall configs are properly set up.

see: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/network-configuration

make sure you've set: Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true if you are using IP v4 addresses.

If there are containers and/or private addresses involved, it might cause connection issues.
See: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/running-client-nodes-behind-nat#limitations

Comment: It works for several hours and then stops. This can still be a connection issue? Ignite client is running on a containerized WebSphere server. I will add both of your recommendations and report back.

Comment: These extra parameters made the system recover faster. We never noticed the JVM pauses before the upgrade to 2.9.0 so we are still looking why they occur.